# Why am I unable to select all the text when clicking a button?

Tags: java, oop, events, awt, actionlistener

I am new to GUI based java programming and would like your help with my query.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Panels
 {
  static Frame f; static TextArea t;
  public static void main(String...xyxxcxcx)
   {
     f=new Frame();
     f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     f.setSize(400,300);
     t=new TextArea(); Button b=new Button("Select All");
     f.add(b); f.add(t);
     t.setText("step into the ring with the game");
     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    t.selectAll();
                }
            }
                );

    f.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

When I click "Select All" button, I expect that the text present in the text area would be selected. However this is not happening. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

It likely **is** happening, the TextAreabut the button has focus, so you never see it. If you tabbed over to the TextArea, you'd likely see all the text selected.

what if you called

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    t.selectAll();
    t.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Question: why use the AWT library? It's about 20 years out of date.

Comment: Swing has not yet been started in our course. Actually I am trying to implement the find next in notepad. I am expecting the text to be highlighted when i click next in a pop up window, exactly like in notepad. But its not happening.